# Admin login function in CodeIgniter PHP not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, admin, codeigniter-3

I tried to make a login function for admins so admins are able to login with using a login form, but its not working. When I click on the login button nothing happens... both when I use the right admin email and password and a wrong input..

This is my adminlogin function in my Auth controller:

```
public function adminlogin() 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_email', 'Admin_email', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('wachtwoord', 'Wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $admin_email = $_POST['admin_email'];
        $admin_wachtwoord = ($_POST['admin_wachtwoord']);

         //check admin in database
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where(array('admin_email'=>$admin_email, 'admin_wachtwoord' => $admin_wachtwoord));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $admin = $query->row();


        if($admin->admin_email) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd als admin");

        //admin sessios
        $_SESSION['admin_logged'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $admin->admin_id;
        $_SESSION['admin_email'] = $admin->admin_email;
        $_SESSION['admin_wachtwoord'] = $admin->admin_wachtwoord;

         //link to admin dashboard
        redirect("IndexController", "refresh");
        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid email or password');
            //if admin doesn't exists reload the admin login form
            redirect("https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/adminlogin" , "refresh");
        }

        }
          //laad alle adminlogin views
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('adminviews/adminlogin');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

My adminlogin.php view page in my adminviews folder:

```
<div class="all-content"> 

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Admin login</center>
        </div>
        </div>

<br>

  <section>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">

            <form action="" method="POST">

              <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>


                    <input class="form-control" name="admin_email" id="admin_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">

            </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="message" class="control-label">Wachtwoord</label>

                    <input class="form-control" name="admin_wachtwoord" id="admin_wachtwoord" type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">

            </div>
                 <div class="form-group">

                    <input name="adminlogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Inloggen" />

            </div>

              </div>

            </form>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>


</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

DATABASE info:

```
table: admin
1. admin_id = primary key
2. admin_email
3. admin_wachtwoord
```

Comment: pass controllername/adminlogin in form action

Comment: ok with base url before controller and function names?

Comment: yes, if you are not set base in view.

Comment: Instead of posting a string of trivial questions with basic syntax errors, try reading through the CodeIgniter documentation at least one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your controller is named `Auth`, you should replace :

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
```

with :

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url('auth/adminlogin');?>" method="POST">
```

You could also use CodeIgniter's [Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html) to write, assuming you've loaded it in your controller :

```
<?php echo form_open('auth/adminlogin'); ?>
```

which would generate the same previous HTML line.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your form tag with the following:

```
<?=form_open('auth/adminlogin');?>
```

And make sure you load the form helper:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: And Make sure PHP short tag is enable on your server.